# Websocket на многостраничном сайте

Tags: javascript, html, websocket

Прочитав несколько статей так и не понял, websocket открывается на текущую страницу или на весь сайт сразу? Т.е. у меня есть надобность открыть сокет на странице А, перейти на страницу B, C и т.д. и отправлять сообщения с них, можно ли это реализовать?

Comment: на сколько я знаю, WebSocket, служить только для обмена данными между Сервером и самим Сайтам, что-то вроде API. Открывать разные страницы, вы можете через JavaScript

Comment: небольшая поправка - для обмена данными- правильно, но данные(или их часть) могут быть интерпритированы как команда+данные. клиентская и серверная часть могут их парсить и выпонять.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Соединение вы можете открывать на любой странице сайта. И отправлять с них или получать сообщения. Весь вопрос нужно ли вам это, или вы хотите сделать что-то другое.

Comment: зря заминусовали.

Answer (score 2):

На каждую страницу - свое соединение. Как минимум потому что, что у вас на каждой странице будет вызывать код, который подключается к websocket-серверу. Каждое подключение имеет уникальный `id`, который и для каждой страницы свой ( если предположить, что на одной странице будет открыто одно соединение )

Какие же решения?

- SPA, тогда у вас всегда одна страница и роутинг происходит без перезагрузки всей страницы
- Вести свою идентификацию подключений и управлять пользователями на ее основании. Например, можно использовать `localStorage` и БД на сервере
  При первом подключении `websocket-a` вы сохраняете логин/сессию пользователя где-нибудь. Если потом какое-то соединение пытается подключиться по этой сессии, то мы объединяем их и работаем как с одним

2 вариант в библиотеке [Socket.io](http://socket.io/) можно реализовать за счет комнат. Все подключения одного пользователя находятся в одной комнате, и мы можем им всем рассылать сообщения или принимать сообщения

Answer (score 0):

можно открыть несколько страниц сайта в одном окне браузера в разных вкладках. И изменяя данные на одной странице, отправить их на сервер, сервер в обработав полученные данные, может отправить необходимую информацию на другую вкладку, а так же на любой другой клиент (браузер, андроид, десктоп). всё дело в логике серверной и клиентской части. это можно реализовать для интернет магазина - выбор на одной вкладке, корзина на другой. можно реализовать и логику, когда с одной страницы идет отправка дданных на сервер, на сервере "складываются данные в шкаф" :) , а когда загружается определённая страница - эти данные из "шкафа" отправляются этой странице. тут дело ограничивается фантазией и опытом программирования. можно также по ws передать команду , которая вызовет переход на другую страницу. В общем, на ws можно организовать кучу всяких плюшек, намного проще и легче чем на другх технологиях. Причём для реализации всех этий фишек сервер нужен намного проще, чем для ajax. единственное ограничение - мало хороших реализаций серверной части. я нашел хорошую библиотеку для java, небольшие изменения и обеспечено прекрасное средство для обмена сервера с клиентом, с защитой, авторизацией... и если клиент долго не производит действий  на странице, на сервере идет контроль времени сессии, при превышении времени сессии - клиент переводится на страницу авторизации.